# Silently install MSI without disabling UAC

Tags: windows-server-2008, uac, msi

I have an MSI file which I produce that I need to install on a number of Windows 2008 machines as part of automated deployment process in a test environment.

When I install the MSI by hand I get a UAC prompt which means that when I try to install with no UI using MSIEXEC, the install fails saying that the install is denied by policy on the machine.

Assuming that I am not allowed to disable UAC on the boxes, what other avenues can I take to circumvent UAC on a machine that I control for a specific MSI package?

**Additional Info**: When running with Verbose and Extra Logging I get a line that reads "*Rejecting product '{guid}': Non-assigned apps are disabled for non-admin users.*"

I am running as an admin user.

**More Additional Info**: The original error message is pretty generic but here it is "
*Info 1625. This installation is forbidden by system policy. Contact your system administrator.*"

Comment: How are you trying to deploy the package - GPO, Script, etc?

Comment: Currently I am simply copying the file to a location on the machine and using PSExec to run MsiExec /q/i against it.

Answer (score 4):

If the recipient machines are members of a domain just create a GPO in that domain to assign the software to the machines and it'll install fine. No scripting is necessary.